# Can i use springboot for designing a middleware application

Tags: spring, transactions

I am planning to redesign my existing middle wire transaction processing system written in core java. is spring boot will be good option. The existing application kind of communicate with multiple delivery channel using pure TCP,Soap,Rest.RabbitMQ,FTP.
Note: The system is doing distributed transaction. i.e For completing a simple client request it working with distributed Transaction

Answer (score 3):

Spring is definitely a good option for creating and designing middle ware applications, Its quite easy with spring to handle multiple communication channels specially SOAP and FTP. For fast processing of transactions, you can use Kafka along with Spring to manipulate transactions distributively.
Kafka being a powerful tool for processing transactions make it easy to handle multiple transactions from different sources.
For creating middle ware applications Spring with Kafka is a best option as it provides best combination for creating micro services along with fast transaction management.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a good idea.

We are using spring boot in our microservice system, that communicates using RabbitMQ, REST, MongoDb driver and even TCP. We have never had any issues with integration or drivers.

You can read about spring boot `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation as well as everything from the package `org.springframework.transaction.annotation`. Maybe it will give you the answer to some of the challenges you already know.

If you have any problems Spring community is quite large.